# What is this fungus growing on tree stumps?

Tags: species-identification, mycology

Location: Austria, Vienna, Ottakring Forest

Time: 2019, Feb 2, 16:02 local time

Size:
[image]
From below; lamellar structure:
[image]

Some more angles:
[image]
[image]
[image]

I found many tree stumps nearby covered by moss, but only this one displaying the fungi. I am not knowledgeable enough to determine the species of the tree.

I first suspected a Ganoderma, but none of the species listed on [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ganoderma) looked very similar.

A better bet might be [Lenzites Betulina](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trametes_betulina) although the pics on Wikipedia always seem more richly coloured than mine. You can check many pics of L. Betulina candidates on [mushroom observer](https://mushroomobserver.org/observer/observation_search?pattern=Lenzites). The L. Betulina in this [Video](https://youtu.be/kEWa-8kiNf8) also seem to have more marked rings.

Edit:
After some searching I am also considering **Trametes Pubescens**, as [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trametes_pubescens) remarks:

> Unlike most other turkey tail-like species of Trametes, the cap surface lacks strongly contrasting zones of color.